# Rails 3 setting a session variable from a link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, session-variables

I have a rails app where a user goes through several views winding up at a form.  The user selects different items on each page that contribute to the final form that they fill out.

I am using query_strings right now which works.  If the user clicks the browser back button it remembers the previous query_string param.  but if the user clicks the button in the site back to the last step in the flow it does not remember the query string.  The query string thing also fails through a failed create action, if the item does not save it re-renders the new action without the query_string...

So I need to make the jump to Sessions and session variables.  I haven't ever done anything with sessions so this is uncharted territory...

So the first step in the flow is the main concern at this point: I am grabbing two categories and the user must select one or the other. I want to set the category.id as a session variable so that then later I can use it to select other things.  Does that make the most sense?

```
<%= link_to "Stores/Field", award_cat_path(:location => "store" ), :class => "buttonOrange" %><br>
    <%= link_to "Corp/Westmont/Vaughan", award_cat_path(:location => "corp" ), :class => "buttonOrange" %>
```

this shows to simple buttons.  The query string is being set with :location, I need to convert this!.  I can create a simple block to loop through the categories but how do I set the category.id as a session variable, and then how would I retrieve it in my next view...

thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try a multi-form gem like wicked, http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked